# SceneKit physics is not behaving as intended

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have 4 walls, 1 ceiling, 1 floor and a furniture. I am dragging my furniture in the room but it is going through walls. I tried everything I know. Still cannot solved the problem. Contact detection is working. My furniture node is not staying on the floor if I don't give it furniture.physicsBody!.damping = 1.0 property. Please check the video : https://youtu.be/1iwq7gvTzA4

```
enum ABC:Int {
    case furni = 1
    case wall = 4
    case floor = 6
}

private func setup() {
    // create the wall geometry
    let wallGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 2000, height: 300)
    wallGeometry.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = "Wallpaper1.png"
    wallGeometry.firstMaterial!.isDoubleSided = false
    wallGeometry.firstMaterial!.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

    let wallWithBaseboardNode = SCNNode(geometry: wallGeometry)
    wallWithBaseboardNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 150, 0)
    wallWithBaseboardNode.physicsBody = .static()
    wallWithBaseboardNode.physicsBody!.restitution = 1.0
    wallWithBaseboardNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ABC.furni.rawValue

    //front
    _wallNode = wallWithBaseboardNode.clone()
    _scene.rootNode.addChildNode(_wallNode)

    //left
    _wallNode = wallWithBaseboardNode.clone()
    _wallNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 150, 0)
    _wallNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, .pi/2)
    _scene.rootNode.addChildNode(_wallNode)

    //right
    _wallNode = wallWithBaseboardNode.clone()
    _wallNode.position = SCNVector3Make(roomDimensions[0], 150, 0)
    _wallNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, -.pi/2)
    _scene.rootNode.addChildNode(_wallNode)

    //back
    _wallNode = wallWithBaseboardNode.clone()
    _wallNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 150, roomDimensions[1])
    _wallNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, .pi/1)
    _scene.rootNode.addChildNode(_wallNode)

    //ceiling
    var ceilingNode = wallWithBaseboardNode.clone()
    ceilingNode = wallWithBaseboardNode.copy() as! SCNNode
    ceilingNode.geometry = (ceilingNode.geometry!.copy() as! SCNGeometry)
    ceilingNode.geometry!.firstMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    ceilingNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    ceilingNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, Float(wallGeometry.height), 0)
    ceilingNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(10, 10, 10)
    ceilingNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, .pi/2)
    _scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ceilingNode)

    //floor
    let floor = SCNFloor()
    floor.reflectionFalloffEnd = 0
    floor.reflectivity = 0

    _floorNode = SCNNode()
    _floorNode.geometry = floor
    _floorNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = "Wood3.jpg"
    _floorNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
    _floorNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
    _floorNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
    _floorNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.mipFilter = .nearest
    _floorNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.isDoubleSided = false

    _floorNode.physicsBody = .static()
    _floorNode.physicsBody!.restitution = 1.0

    //_floorNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ABC.furni.rawValue

    _scene.rootNode.addChildNode(_floorNode)
}
```

And this is the code for my furniture node

```
private func addFurniture() {
    let furnitureScene = SCNScene(named: "a.dae", inDirectory: "assets.scnassets/models/", options: nil)!
    let furniture = furnitureScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "a", recursively: true)!

    furniture.physicsBody = .dynamic()
    furniture.physicsBody!.restitution = 1.0
    furniture.physicsBody!.damping = 1.0

    furniture.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ABC.wall.rawValue

    _scene.rootNode.addChildNode(furniture)

    scnView.prepare(_scene, shouldAbortBlock: nil)

    _furniture = furniture

    scnView.debugOptions = [.showPhysicsShapes, .showPhysicsFields]
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between contactTestBitMask and collisionBitMask?  If you do, what's the purpose of assigning contactTestBitMask to your nodes?

Comment: @ElTomato No I am not really sure. Would you please guide me to fix the issue? I am new to SceneKit. What should I do to stop that from happening. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, set the physics body of the affectedByGravity property to false for concerned parties.

Comment: @ElTomato What do you mean by "concerned parties"? I have set affectedByGravity to furniture node but it did not change a thing. It has been days. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the furniture manualy (i.e. not using forces), change the body type to .kinematic

When you move the node , you can perform [contactTest(with:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsworld/1512841-contacttest) which will return you a list of contacts if you hit the walls. In the [renderer(_:willRenderScene:atTime:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate/1523483-renderer) you can then fix the position of the furniture to "fix" the wall penetration offset against the wall.

You can see my solution of a similar problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915698/1389597

Hope this helps, i've spent several days trying to figure this out :)

Comment: This fixed my issue! I don't understand why Apple doesn't just implement this by default in the SCNPhysicsContactDelegate. Why allow buggy physics to save CPU / GPU processing? It doesn't make a lot of sense.